# addthis sharing to Facebook app instead of m.facebook.com

Tags: facebook, mobile, addthis

When a user clicks to share to Facebook, they get the popup with the little yellow "contacting Facebook". That's fine on a desktop or laptop.

However, on a mobile phone or tablet, this is not so convenient, because users are not normally logged-in at https://m.facebook.com

Is there a way to redirect them to the Facebook app (where they're already logged in), instead of redirecting them to https://m.facebook.com in their browser?

Thank you!

I've searched the web and addthis support  but cannot find an answer.

Comment: No there is not.

Comment: Thank you WizKid. I appreciate your answer :) If you can think of any other way to accomplish such a thing, please let me know.